# Not sure what to put in the objects string variable

Tags: java, oop, object

I am very confused and im pretty sure im doing this the wrong way. This is just a random application that i am making to understand programming a little better so far I have this!

```
public class Player {
        public void player(String name,String type,int things){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            name = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println("you entered: "+ name);
    }
        public int[] playerMove(int x, int y){
            x = 3;
            y = 2;
            return new int[] {x , y};
        }

        public static void main(String args[]){
            System.out.println("Enter your players name: ");
            Player Devin = new Player(What do i put here?, "class", 3);

        }
}
```

I put where I am having the problem in the code. Im not sure what to put in the objects variable!

Comment: `null` would be appropriate

Comment: where did you define Player constructor?

Comment: right above the main method

Comment: thanks and i relize i didnt make the constructor right ive been coding in c++ and there constructor is public void

Comment: and change the constructor name to class name too

Comment: You might want to read some docs about [constuctor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

Comment: Arguments are useful to provide inputs to methods when calling the method. For example: add(1, 2) allows adding 1 and 2. If the add() methods assignes values to the arguments, there's no point in having arguments. Just use local variables inside the method. player() and playerMove() have no reason to have any argument, since they completely ignore their value.

Comment: Did my answer below help?

Answer (score 1):

You should not read values from input in constructor, constructor should only be used to initialize variables. In your original code the `Player` class is not reusable because it depends on where the `name` variable comes from (And it can be only standard input). Serializing, cloning and making arrays of `Player`s will become so hard or impossible because every time a `Player` object is created it blocks the main thread and asks user to enter a name.

This code is a little better:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    public Player(String name, String type,int things){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName()  {
       return name;
    }
    public int[] playerMove(int x, int y){
        x = 3;
        y = 2;
        return new int[] {x , y};
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Enter your players name: ");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name = in.nextLine();
        Player devin = new Player(name, "class", 3);
        System.out.println("You entered " + devin.getName());
    }
```

}